# Parse variables from array to method

Tags: php, oop, url-routing

I am trying to create my own little MVC system, its working very well, but one thing i have problems with is parsing variables to methods.

You see i use URL rewritting to make every url point at index.php, and then set up the page by the url data like /email/1/34/

I am then creating an object such as here.

```
<?php 
$page = $urlsplit[0];

$variables = array($urlsplit[1], $urlsplit[2]);
$page->callmethod($variables);
?>
```

What i want it to do is that instead of parsing the array to the method, it should do it like this.

```
$page->callmethod($variables[0], $variables[1]);
```

Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: $page->callmethod($urlsplit[1], $urlsplit[2]); no?

Comment: A suggestion here for SEO its better when you have some information in the url so perhaps its better when you try something like this "/controller/action/variable/value/variable2/value2"

Comment: Basicly that is what i am doing, just made this to make clear what i want. But thanks for the advice, i am sure others will find it usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a call like `$page->callmethod($variables[0], $variables[1])` dynamically you can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
call_user_func_array(array($page, 'callmethod'), $variables);
```

Comment: That is working perfectly exactly what i needed. Now my MVC system is fully functional!

Answer (score 0):

Actually , it would make more sense to use some kind of regular expression for splitting the URL in multiple parts.

Consider this fragment:

```
/*
$url = '/user/4/edit'; // from $_GET
*/
$pattern = '/(?P<controller>[a-z]+)(:?\/(?:(?P<id>[0-9]+)\/)?(?P<action>[a-z]+))?/';
if ( !preg_match( $pattern, $url, $segments ) )
{
    // pattern did not match
}

$controller = new $segments['controller'];
if ( method_exists( $controller, $segments['action'] ) )
{
    $action = $segments['action'];
    $param =  $segments['id'];
}
else
{
    $controller = new ErrorController;
    $action = 'notFound';
    $param = $url;
}

$response = $controller->$action( $param );
```

Of course in a real MVC implementation there would be additional things going on, but this should explain the concept.